# c# code to find exact date difference as in vb

Tags: c#, vb.net

In `VB` there is a function called `DateDiff()`. But in C# it is not available. I want a function or any code in C# that can perform the same DateDiff function as in VB..

```
Dim datTim1 As Date = #1/4/2001#
Dim datTim2 As Date = #1/9/2001#
Dim wD As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Weekday, datTim1, datTim2)
Dim wY As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, datTim1, datTim2)
```

I want to do this in C#...

Comment: Why have you tagged html, javascript and jquery when you want someone who knows c# to answer the question? please retag.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. How to Retag it??

Comment: click 'edit' at the bottom of your post, and from there you will see tags. Delete the tags there and put in c# instead

Comment: Without trying to sound too much like a c#nt: did you try googling `c# datediff` ? Since it has code for this in all of the first 10 answers.

Comment: thanx for the link, i checked it just supports difference between two dates, i need entire method to work as DateDiff in VB, actually i had that before, but i lost. There is somekind of class is there..

Comment: Have a look at `DateTime`, `DateTime.Subtract` and `TimeSpan` (even in VB.net you should do it like this ..)

Comment: If you want to have exactly the same semantics, you *can* reference `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly in your C# code and then just use the `DateDiff` method from the [`DateAndTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.dateandtime(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Ah you posted that comment just as I was adding an answer that says exactly the same thing...

Comment: i have found the class to use, no need to refer the assembly, there is a class for that, anyway thanx for all to your usefull comments

Comment: thanx everyone. I solved this.
But without understanding the question some guy downgraded the vote. Let him long live..

Comment: that guy name is Himanshu.MarJAVA who doesn't have time to read entire question

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. That question is about number of days only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add to your C# project a reference to the .Net assembly `Microsoft.VisualBasic`
2. Call `Microsoft.VisualBasic.DateAndTime.DateDiff()` with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: anyway i accept this answer too. thanx, i will use this in future. such a good one.

Comment: Probably not the best long-term solution, but great that this is an option as part of a conversion effort. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own **DateDiff()** function:

```
public enum Intervals
{
    Days,
    Months,
    Years
}

public static int DateDiff(Intervals eInterval, System.DateTime dtInit, System.DateTime dtEnd)
{
    if (dtEnd < dtInit)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Init date should be previous to End date.");

    switch (eInterval) {
        case Intervals.Days:
            return (dtEnd.AddDays - dtInit).TotalDays;
        case Intervals.Months:
            return ((dtEnd.Year - dtInit.Year) * 12) + dtEnd.Month - dtInit.Month;
        case Intervals.Years:
            return dtEnd.Year - dtInit.Year;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Incorrect interval code.");
    }
}
```